# DevExpress: вызов события GridView

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, devexpress

Не могу найти метод, с помощью которого в C# можно было бы сгенерировать GridView Event, наподобие методов on..... для WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

В публичном АПИ таких методов нет. Используйте альтернативные способы решить исходную задачу, не прибегая к насильственному генерированию событий.